# How to convert symfony gedmo annotation to PHP 8 Attributes

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, doctrine, slug

I'm working on Symfony 6 PHP 8 project and i'm using gedmo doctrine extension .

I can't find a full documentation about converting gedmo annotation to PHP 8  Attributes.

I'm tring to convert like this :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"title"})
 */
private $slug;

#[Gedmo\Slug(fields: title)]
```

but it doesn't work !

How can i use gedmo with PHP 8 Attributes  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rector](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector) supports this. The rule comes from [rector-doctrine](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector-doctrine/blob/main/src/Set/DoctrineSetList.php), which is included with the standard install method.

Follow the rector install guide and edit the rector.php config to add the required rules.

Rector also has rule sets for updating Symfony to see [rector-symfony](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector-symfony).

Example of converting the Doctrine and Gedmo annotation to PHP 8 attributes.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use Rector\Config\RectorConfig;
use Rector\Doctrine\Set\DoctrineSetList;

return static function (RectorConfig $rectorConfig): void {

    $rectorConfig->sets([
        DoctrineSetList::DOCTRINE_CODE_QUALITY,
        DoctrineSetList::ANNOTATIONS_TO_ATTRIBUTES,
        DoctrineSetList::GEDMO_ANNOTATIONS_TO_ATTRIBUTES,
    
    ]);
};
```

e.g. converts this

```
/**
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"title"})
 * @ORM\Column(length=128, unique=true)
 */
private $slug;
```

to

```
#[ORM\Column(length: 128, unique: true)]
#[Gedmo\Slug(fields: ['title'])]
private $slug;
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to do the whole class property with attributes.
the fields property at slug needs to be an array.

```
#[\Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\Slug(fields: ['name'])]
#[\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column(
    type: 'string',
    length: 255,     
)]
```

Comment: maybe you want to check out, if rector could help you to automatically transform your annotations to attributes.
see https://getrector.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-annotations-to-attributes

Comment: i got an error about fields : unknown named parameter fields

Comment: https://github.com/doctrine-extensions/DoctrineExtensions/blob/main/doc/sluggable.md gives you a nice overview, nice examples